# Bulk insert to mongo DB using threadpool inside a celery task

Tags: django, mongodb, multithreading, celery, threadpool

When I tried bulk insert to mongoDB collection inside threadpool mongoDB memory goes on increase. What is the best way to implement this in a celery task?